# What's wrong with this mod_rewrite statement?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to replicate the functionality of `mod_alias` which I can't use directly because I'm on shared hosting, and Alias statements don't work in .htaccess.

What I want to achieve is essentially

```
Alias /manual /www/customer/some_other_dir/manual
```

I am trying mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/manual/(.*) /www/customer/some_other_dir/manual/%1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

this will never match any calls to `www.example.com/manual`.

Why not? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Pekka - Check my revision before putting that live! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/manual(/(.*))?$ /www/customer/some_other_dir/$2 [L]
```

The `?` means optional for the `/` character in addition to the kleene closure on the `.` to ensure  `/manual`, `/manual/` and `/manual/a/b/c` although I gather a slash is usually added by apache pre-rewrite engine anyway.

A quick test on my box shows this rule also passes the query string:

```
/manual/a/b?c=d -> /www/customer/some_other_dir/manual/$2
```

Comment: I have a follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188444/mod-rewrite-to-absolute-path-in-htaccess-turning-up-404

Answer (score 1):

Tun off Multiviews option

```
Options -Multiviews
```

and i think, it's expect / at end of requested URL.

Something like this will match `www.example.com/manual` too.

```
RewriteRule ^/manual/?(.*) /www/customer/some_other_dir/manual/%1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```