# mod_rewrite to absolute path in .htaccess - turning up 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to map a number of directories in a URL:

```
www.example.com/manual
www.example.com/login
```

to directories outside the web root.

My web root is

```
/www/htdocs/customername/site
```

the manual I want to redirect to is in

```
/www/customer/some_other_dir/manual
```

In mod_alias, this would be equal to

```
Alias /manual /www/customer/some_other_dir/manual
```

but as I have access only to `.htaccess`, I can't use Alias, so I have to use `mod_rewrite`.

What I have got right now after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188274/whats-wrong-with-this-mod-rewrite-statement/2188317#2188317) is the following:

```
RewriteRule ^manual(/(.*))?$ /www/htdocs/customername/manual/$2 [L]
```

this works in the sense that requests are recognized and redirected properly, but I get a 404 that looks like this (note the absolute path):

```
The requested URL /www/htdocs/customername/manual/resourcename.htm 
was not found on this server.
```

However, I have checked with PHP: `echo file_exists(...)` and that file definitely exists.

why would this be? According to the mod_rewrite docs, this is possible, even in a .htaccess file. I understand that when doing mod_rewrite in .htaccess, there will be an automated prefix, but not to absolute paths, will it?

It shouldn't be a rights problem either: It's not in the web root, but within the FTP tree to which only one user, the main FTP account, has access.

I can change the web root in the control panel anytime, but I want this to work the way I described.

This is shared hosting, so I have no access to the error logs.

I just checked, this is not a wrongful 301 redirection, just an internal rewrite.

Comment: What is the version? (sorry if you mentioned, I couldn'tspot any versions in the question)

Comment: Good question actually. I think it's 2.0, but I'll have to check.

Comment: I think the destination part is not an absolute path, it rewrites the URL meaning http://www.foo.com/www/htdocs/customername ... would need to exist.

Comment: Yup, that seems to be the problem. Is there any way to make mod_rewrite accept absolute URLs like `Alias`?

Comment: I wrote a follow-up question with this issue specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191583/absolute-paths-in-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK mod_rewrite works at the 'protocol' level (meaning on the wire HTTP). So I suspect you are getting HTTP 302 with your directory path in the location.

So I'm afraid you might be stuck unless.. your hosting lets you follow symbolic links; so you can link to that location (assuming you have shell access or this is possible using FTP or your control panel) under your current document root.

**Edit:** It actually mentions [URL-file phase hook in the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalAPI) so now I suspect the [directory directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory) aren't allowing enough permissions.

Comment: Nope, mod_rewrite usually works on redirect level only if specifically told so by a `http://` prefixed URL, or the `[R]` flag. Good point though, I will check whether it is wrongly making a redirect instead of a rewrite.

Comment: No, it seems there is no redirect, this is an internal rewrite.

Comment: Yep, sorry. You are right. It is internal. But still I think mod_rewrite works at the 'URL' level only.

Answer (score 4):

In .htaccess, you cannot rewrite to files outside the wwwroot.

You need to have a symbolic link within the webroot that points to the location of the manual.

Then in your .htaccess you need the line:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

or maybe a little more blindly

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Then you can

```
RewriteRule ^manual(/(.*))?$ /www/htdocs/customername/site/manual/$2 [L]
```

where manual under site is a link to /www/customer/some_other_dir/manual

You create the symlink on the command line with:

```
ln -s /www/htdocs/customername/site/manual /www/customer/some_other_dir/manual
```

But I imagine you're on shared hosting without shell access, so look into creating symbolic links within CPanel,Webmin, or whatever your admin interface is.  There are php/cgi scripts that do it as well.  Of course, you're still limited to the permissions that the host has given you.  If they don't allow you to follow symlinks as a policy, you cannot override that within your .htaccess.

Answer (score -1):

This tells you what you need to know.
    The requested URL /www/htdocs/customername/manual/resourcename.htm 
    was not found on this server.
It interprets `RewriteRule ^manual(/(.*))?$ /www/htdocs/customername/manual/$2 [L]` to mean rewrite example.com/manual/ as if it were example.com/www/htdocs/customername/manual/.

Try

```
 RewriteRule ^manual(/(.*))?$ /customername/manual/$2 [L]
```

instead.

Comment: The problem with this is that the directory I want to redirect to is outside the web root, so I can't reference it relatively. Let's say I'm in `/www/htdocs/customername/site` and that is the web root. If this is the problem, do you know how can I change this behaviour so that the implicit directory prefix is not used?